# Что нужно для отправки http запросов и получения на них ответов в C#

Tags: c#, http, api

Условия задачи: нужно получить через http-запрос к Api проекта. Решил, что лучше реализовать всё на C#. Вопрос в том, как отправить http запрос и получить ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, воспользоваться HttpClient:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
        var result = await client.PostAsync("/api/foo", new StringContent(postParams));
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
```

где **postParams** - параметры запроса

Comment: Было бы понятно, если бы создатели Api этого проекта в документации показывали запросы и параметры в виде URL. Но они показали параметры в виде заголовков HTTP запроса вот так (Authorization: token <auth_key>). Тогда как в HttpClient добавить заголовок к запросу?

Comment: @DrGunn `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("scheme", "param");`
или в более общем случае `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("HEADERNAME", "HEADERVALUE");`